# Centering wx.TextCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm having difficulties centering the text within a wx.TextCtrl (as shown in the photoshopped illustration below). -- For some reason, it always prints LEFT aligned, instead of CENTERED.

[image: Illustration of desired output]

Could someone please point me to the proper "styles" OR tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import wx

class SimplePanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        myTextCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1,
                                 style=wx.TE_CENTRE,
                                 size=(100, -1), pos=(10, 10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()

    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'Simple Panel') 
    myPanel = SimplePanel(frame, -1)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your code works fine (centered) for me on Windows XP with Python 2.6 and  wxPython 2.8.11. Maybe you have some other code before it preventing this?

Comment: Works fine on my setup: OS Windows-XP-SP3, Python 2.7.1, wxPython 2.8.11.0.

Comment: This does not work on OSX as described in [http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/10010](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/10010)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work fine on Windows but I was using both OSX and Windows for development and `wx.TE_CENTRE` does not appear to work on OSX.  This was defect was reported many years ago (http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/10010).

Answer (score 1):

(Edited after clarification)

There was a bug once in wxPython which broke TE_CENTRE for some OSes:

http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/ANN-wxPython-2-8-9-1-td2367679.html

Try updating to the latest version perhaps.